# Jquery data function removes zero from the beginning of string

Tags: jquery

I have something like that:

```
<input id="zip_code" type="text" value="" data-existing-value="09458" name="zip_code"/>
```

I am trying to get an existing zip code value from data parameter using:

```
$("#zip_code).val($('#zip_code').data('existing-value'));
```

And for some reason zero is removed...and all i am getting for the text field value is : "9458" without a leading zero...

How can i keep zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$("#zip_code).attr('data-existing-value');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `attr('data-existing-value')`.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7579